# How to set an input limits on list with python 3

Tags: list, python-3.x

```
#room B register
#matrix method
roomB = [[],[]]
```

I am planning to enter only 3 units in here roomB=[[  ],[  ]] and if the first unit full, the system should suggest another unit.

```
def func():
    row = int(input("Choose 0 or 1:"))
    if (row == 0):                  # ROW 0 IS FOR HOUSE 1:
            name = input("Enter your room name: ")
            print("Enter M or N")       #M for master room
            room_type = input("")         #N for normal room
            for u in roomB:      #3 units in roomB[0]
              if(len(u)<3):
                if (room_type == "M"):
                    return roomB[0].append([room_type,name,140])
                if (room_type == "N"):
                    return roomB[0].append([room_type,name,140])
```

Comment: What is your problem? Do you receive any error or unexpected behavior?

Comment: which output you expect?

Comment: I didn't receive any error but I want my output to insert only 3 units on my list do u have any suggestion that I should chg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
roomB = [[],[]]

def update(row): # takes sublist as argument
    if len(roomB[row]) < 3: # checks if sublist length is less than 3
        name = input("Enter your name: ")
        room_type = input("Enter room type : M (master room) or N (normal room) : ").lower()
        roomB[row].append([room_type,name,140])
        return "your room no. is {} at row {}".format(roomB[row].index([room_type,name,140]) + 1, row) # returns string stating status


def func():
    if len(roomB[0]) < 3 and len(roomB[1]) < 3: # ask for prompt only if space available in both sublist
        row = int(input("Choose 0 or 1: ")) # allow to select row
        return update(row)
    elif len(roomB[0]) >= 3 and len(roomB[1]) < 3: # selects default sublist if no space on other sublist
        print("No room available at 0 , selected 1 ")
        return update(1) # returns string stating status
    elif len(roomB[0]) < 3 and len(roomB[1]) >= 3: # selects default sublist if no space on other sublist
        print("No room available at 1 , selected 0 ")
        return update(0)
    else: # in case any error occurs it goes here
        print("Errrr.......")
        print("room stat....: ", roomB)

while len(roomB[0]) <= 3 or len(roomB[1]) <= 3: # loop will flow if length of both sublist is greater than or equals to 3
    if len(roomB[0]) != 0 or len(roomB[1]) != 0: # won't ask for confirmation if all all lists are empty (skips prompts for initial) 
        cond = input("do you want to continue?(Y/N) ").lower()
        if cond == "n":
            break # break the loop if pressed n or N otherwise continue to execute
    elif len(roomB[0]) >= 3 and len(roomB[1]) >= 3: # error message to print if no space left in sublists
        print("No room available.. Sorry for inconvinience.")
    print(func())
```

Comment: hi thank you for your solution btw may i ask why we should use format instead of append? And i want the room which has only 1 master bedroom and 2 normal bedroom

Comment: I have used append. append will just append the element to list and hence it(function) will return None when you write `return list.append(<element>)`. format is string formatting in python. as I have already written it returns string

Comment: is there any possible way to do looping beside using if and else statement?

Comment: you can use try/except block if you want.